# Is there a word for "underneath a tree"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there an adjective to describe an object (*edit:* e.g. a dog house or a headstone; the object is not necessarily a living thing) on the ground and underneath a tree? I thought of *"treeside"*, but its meaning is obviously a bit different.

Comment: I don't think so.  You could use "shaded", but that doesn't specifically imply a tree.  "Arboreal" means "relating to trees" but doesn't imply underneath.

Comment: If there were, *Desire Under the Elms* might have had a different name. If you want a rhyming phrase instead, perhaps *in the lee of a tree*?

Comment: I don't suppose "hypodendric" is a word?

Comment: @MattGutting What does the word mean? It's a bit too "scientific" (much more so than the "subarboreal" in the answers below) anyway.

Comment: that was a bit of a joke :-) _hypo-_ is a Classical Greek prefix meaning "under"; _-dendric_ is a hypothetical adjectival form from the Classical Greek _dendron_, meaning "tree": thus "under a tree." But it's not an actual English word.

Comment: There is "underwood" also for growing things under trees.

Comment: User1551: is there such a word in your language?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Bosky](http://www.extelligence.co.uk/dictionary/b/)**   (literary) 1. Covered by bushes, shrubs or trees. 2. Shaded by trees or bushes.

**[Embower](http://en.academic.ru/dic.nsf/cide/57711/Embower)** To cover with a bower; to shelter with trees. [Written also {imbower}.]

Answer (score 7):

[Subarboreal](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/subarboreal) is pretty close in strict definition, and could be extended to being used simply as an adjective to describe something as being beneath a tree. It is normally used to describe a species of animal or plant.

> def: living or thriving under trees

See also: [arboreal](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/arboreal) (leaving in/among or relating to trees)

From Latin *arbor* (tree) -> *arboreus* (of trees) and *sub* (beneath)

Comment: I'll upvote the word for being on the right track, but I don't think it really satisfies his request. Living or thriving under trees is not the some as being under a tree.

Answer (score 4):

Try *subarboreal*. I don't see an entry for it at merriam-webster.com, but I see it used in at least [one scientific paper](http://www.archive.org/stream/ants_06422/ants_06422_djvu.txt) with the meaning you have in mind.

There is also a link mentioning the word on the [World English-Language Scrabble Players Association](http://www.wespa.org/features/segetal.shtml), whence I deduce (without checking) that it is in at least one officially-recognized Scrabble dictionary.